# How to get the index of a clicked button inside an item of a listview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, buttonclick, flutter-listview

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctGnG.jpg)
Look at the delete icon button on the screenshot. 
I want to get the index of the clicked button in order to delete the selected item of the listview. What should I do? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Share a simplified code

Answer (score 1):

in this example I show how you can do this easily, creating a list with the names of the items and a function that returns a widget:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final List<String> items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];  //creating a list of the title of the items

  Widget itemWidget({String text, VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(                            //widget that will be called on the ListView
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 50,),
          Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),   //receiving the text
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: onPressed,    //receiving the function
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return itemWidget(
            text: items[index],
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                items.removeAt(index);          //remove the item at the current index
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The UI:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed.